# How to generate UsernameToken for WS-Security?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, ws-security

I have some web service (wrote in Java) and I need create client for it in .NET. The WebService has WS-Security and need PasswordDigest. 
First of all, I've tested it in SoapUI and it's works for:

```
POST http://192.168.100.101:8181/services/ws/SomeService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="someMethod"
Content-Length: 971
Host: 192.168.100.101:8181
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)

<soap:Envelope xmlns:not="http://existing-domain.com/op/integration/services" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2C1E2DE2B61EBB94E115572099598331">
            <wsse:Username>SOME_LOGIN</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">rcSb6Hd8btcI9g6JvO7dGdiTBTI=</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">PCoVwJm9oEXtusx6gkMb7w==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2019-05-07T06:19:19.824Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <not:someMethod/>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In the next step I've prepared simple client in .NET and check with Wireshark what it sends:

```
POST /services/ws/SomeService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="someMethod"
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
Host: 192.168.100.101:8181
Content-Length: 1124
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

<soap:Envelope xmlns:not="http://existing-domain.com/op/integration/services" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-85707168-b5c6-47dc-93e9-45afa466fa2a" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>SOME_LOGIN</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">g112a9eHPR1hXD4UH+Lh3o8JV/o=</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>EiUbo2DbXMGhM26fT+ZkJQ==</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created>2019-05-07T06:27:59Z</wsu:Created>
      </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <not:someMethod />
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Unfortunatelly I allways got 500 status code and response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <soap:Code>
                <soap:Value>soap:Sender</soap:Value>
                <soap:Subcode>
                    <soap:Value xmlns:ns1="http://ws.apache.org/wss4j">ns1:SecurityError</soap:Value>
                </soap:Subcode>
            </soap:Code>
            <soap:Reason>
                <soap:Text xml:lang="en">A security error was encountered when verifying the message</soap:Text>
            </soap:Reason>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm pretty sure it's appear because of authorization problem (I had same message in SoapUI if provided wrong credentials).

The section  in my client is created with:

```
UsernameToken t = new UsernameToken("SOME_LOGIN", "SOME_PASSWORD", PasswordOption.SendHashed);
string usernameTokenSection = t.GetXml(new XmlDocument()).OuterXml.ToString();
```

There is a few articels how to create PasswordDigits (*Base64( SHA1(password + nonce + created) )*), Nonce (*Base64(RandomString)*) or Created date but I can't find what is `wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2C1E2DE2B61EBB94E115572099598331"` and how to create it. Above code where I get xml from UsernameToken returns complete section so I decided to use it, but I noticed that it append `wsu:Id="SecurityToken-85707168-b5c6-47dc-93e9-45afa466fa2a"` (instead of `wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2C1E2DE2B61EBB94E115572099598331"`). I can change the name and remove `-` characters but it's nothing changed and I still get 500 Internal Server Error with message "**A security error was encountered when verifying the message**".

So, my question is how to generate UsernameToken section with proper `wsu:Id="UsernameToken-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`data? What is it - just random string or some hash created based on username and password?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! I noticed that SOAP sent from .NET client doesn't have attribute `EncodingType` in `Nonce` node. After little modification in code:

```
UsernameToken t = new UsernameToken("SOME_LOGIN", "SOME_PASSWORD", PasswordOption.SendHashed);
string usernameTokenSection = t.GetXml(new XmlDocument()).OuterXml.ToString().Replace("<wsse:Nonce", "<wsse:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\"");
```

Everything works!

Whole code for .NET client:

```
public static void Execute()
{            
        UsernameToken usernameTokenSection = new UsernameToken("SOME_LOGIN", "SOME_PASSWORD", PasswordOption.SendHashed);

        HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequest();
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(@"<soap:Envelope xmlns:not=""http://existing-domain.com/op/integration/services"" xmlns:soap=""http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"">" +
              "<soap:Header>" +
                @"<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"" xmlns:wsu=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"">"+
                    usernameTokenSection.GetXml(new XmlDocument()).OuterXml.ToString().Replace("<wsse:Nonce", "<wsse:Nonce EncodingType=\"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary\"") +
                "</wsse:Security>" +
              "</soap:Header>"+
              "<soap:Body>"+
                "<not:someMethod/>"+
              "</soap:Body>"+
            "</soap:Envelope>");

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }

        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(soapResult);
            }
        }
}

public static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest()
{
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://192.168.100.101:8181/services/ws/SomeService");

        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate");
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action=\"someMethod\"";
        //NOTE: below it's not necessary
        //webRequest.Host = "192.168.100.101:8181";
        //webRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        //webRequest.UserAgent = "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)";

        return webRequest;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
        try
        {
            Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

}
```

PS. For using `UsernameToken` class you have to using `Microsoft.Web.Services2` reference, you can add it by Nuget from here: [Microsoft.Web.Services2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.Services2/)

PPS. I know that there is simpler way by `Add Service Reference...` but it require additional classes and modifications for creating `Security` node in `Header`, so I decided to send raw xml and manipulate it directly.